# Post back list of addresses and send out emails FAIL ON SMTP

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Post an address back to the POST method. I want to send an email to that address:

```
 [HttpPost, ActionName("Index")]
    public ActionResult IndexPOST(SuppliersIndexVM allSuppliers)
    {
        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
        SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");

        mail.From = new MailAddress("martin.lagan@umac-solutions.co.uk");
        mail.To.Add("martin.lagan@umac-solutions.co.uk");
        mail.Subject = "Order";
        mail.Body = "I would like to order the following...";

        SmtpServer.Send(mail);

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

Error is coming from last line: SmptpServer.Sed(mail)...

The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. b20sm10938791wiw.4 - gsmtp

Any ideas guys.....also how can I add tables etc to the email i am sending...cheers

Comment: Did you read the error message? You must authenticate with the server. What is the question here?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the error is due to Gmail requiring authentication before it can allow you to send email through its' SMTP server. You can try to add the below code to get rid of this issue.

```
SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;
SmtpServer.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
SmtpServer.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("emailaddress","password");
```

Comment: Instead of writing the authentication info in code, you can use the `mailSettings` directive in Web.config: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms164242.aspx